# Is saying "It is more plausible to believe" correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I want to say to someone, who thinks Muslim communities are hiding ISIS members of their own accord, that the more believable scenario would be that those communities are under ISIS's control and constant threats that they have no choice. 
So is it correct to use the word *plausible* like this?

> Wouldn't be more plausible to believe that these communities are under
>   ISIS's control?

Answer (score 3):

"Plausible" is a good word here, but "to believe" is unnecessary. It would be more natural to say:

> Wouldn't **it** be more plausible that these communities are under ISIS's control?

Examples of the use of plausible here http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/plausible very rarely include the infinitive of a verb after plausible.

To use "believe", try this:

> Don't you believe it more plausible that these communities are under
>   ISIS's control?

Comment: You raise a good point. If something is more plausible, then it is by inference more believable.